# Only certain svg rectangle(s) drawing in browser

Tags: html, svg

I am having problems displaying a grid of SVG rectangles, only the first rectangle listed in my html file is showing up.

I changed around the width and height for the first one and the coordinates. The rectangle scaled/moved just fine.

```
<body>
<section align="CENTER">
<svg width=250 height=250>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=0 y=0/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=50 y=0/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=100 y=0/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=150 y=0/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=200 y=0/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=0 y=50/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=50 y=50/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=100 y=50/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=150 y=50/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=200 y=50/>   
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=0 y=100/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=50 y=100/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=100 y=100/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=150 y=100/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=200 y=100/>  
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=0 y=150/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=50 y=150/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=100 y=150/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=150 y=150/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=200 y=150/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=0 y=200/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=50 y=200/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=100 y=200/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=150 y=200/>
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=200 y=200/>
</svg>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0/` is being parsed as an attribute value, so the first `<rect` tag is being parsed as

```
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0/">
```

rather than

```
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" />
```

as you intend. When the browser (Firefox in my case) reads this, it sees a `<rect>` without a close tag. Subsequent `<rect>`s in the svg are parsed as being within the first one, which does nothing.

Either quote the values of the xml attributes, or put a space in front of the slash as I've done in [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fybmpb8b/).

Comment: this fix made it work, would vote up your answer, but I am not at 15 reputation yet